# Webform send multiple email

Tags: 6, webforms

I have created a webform. There is one field "Send invitation to your friends" . In this field user can enter their friends email ids (Comma seperated) For example A@gmail.com,B@yahoo.com,C@hotmail.com etc. I want to send a common email "Welcome and join us" to all these people. Can anyone help me, how can I proceed?

Comment: I am not fully sure how to achieve this. It might be possible with the use of tokens and/or rules, but I am sure someone else can chime in. I don't want to assume the full scope of what the webform is for, but if it's just inviting people to the site, have you considered just using http://drupal.org/project/invite ?

Answer (score 5):

You can send custom emails to addresses submitted in the form. When creating the form, you have to select 'email' for the field type. Once you've done that, go to the 'Emails' tab in the webform, and add a new email using the 'Component value' menu; you should see your Email field in there (you can add as many of these as you want). This sets it up to send an email to the email address entered in the form, in your case the friends' email addresses.

From there you can customise the email options.

Edit: Whoops, this answer is for Drupal 7 specifically, but (if I remember correctly) the option exists in Drupal 6 as well.

Comment: thanks, i didn't even noticed this component type and i was about to create a function to implement this fonctionnality :)